# Android UI layout that can display 4 ListFragment of various sizes the way just like displaying one very long ListFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listfragment

There are 4 ListFragment in the main layout, like code below. What layout or property should I apply to guarantee all elements of all 4 `ListFragment` will be displayed sequentially, no matter how long each `ListFragment`might be?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/todolist_newitem"
        android:name="com.example.tek.first.servant.todolist.fragment.NewItemAddedFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/todolist_displayfragment_incomplete_items"
        android:name="com.example.tek.first.servant.todolist.fragment.display.IncompleteDetailedItemsDisplayFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/todolist_newitem" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/todolist_displayfragment_simple_todoitems"
        android:name="com.example.tek.first.servant.todolist.fragment.display.SimpleToDoItemsDisplayFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/todolist_displayfragment_incomplete_items" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/todolist_displayfragment_completed_items"
        android:name="com.example.tek.first.servant.todolist.fragment.display.CompletedDetailedItemsDisplayFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/todolist_displayfragment_simple_todoitems" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, and `ScrollView`, with `layout_height` both as `wrap_content` and `match_parent`.
 
If the first `ListFragment` is too long(more than screen height), in both `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`situations, it will "hide"/"cover" the remaining three; if the first `ListFragment` is almost as long as the screen, e.g. it takes up 2/3 of the screen, the remaining three `ListFragment` can only be scrollably displayed in the last 1/3 part of the screen, and the 2nd might "cover" the 3rd, etc.
As for `ScrollView`, there was only one line of item for each `ListFragment`, thus only 4 lines of item in the whole screen, with each item scrollable for its `ListFragment`.
None of the situations mentioned above meet my requirements. What I want is just frank displays of all `ListFragment` sequentially both in order of fragments and elements in the fragment, just like the way only one very long `ListFragment` will be displayed. What should I do?
I know `TabLayout` is the least option, or combine all 4 `ListFragment` data in `ArrayList` into one. But what else could be done? Any better solution?

Comment: does your device screen magically get bigger? Probably not so no you cant guarantee it always shows every item in the list

Comment: You will probably be better off using a single ListView and somehow making sections within the LIstView/adapter. It's easy enough to use multiple row types, so I would start there.

Answer (score -1):

change `Relative` to `LinearLayout`(vertical) with `layout_height="match_parent"` and then in fragment set `layout_weight="1"` and `layout_height="0dp"`. Weight works like % that means it provides equal height(because of value 1) to all view in one viewgroup.
Thanks.